# Converting null literal or possible null warning on DataRow in foreach

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

Updated my .NET Core 3.1 console application to use Nullables feature and have the following `foreach` loop.

```cs
DataTable profiles = DB.ListProfiles();
// CS8600 warning here
//               v
foreach (DataRow r in profiles.Rows)
{
    // processing code here
}


static public DataTable ListProfiles()
{
    DataTable t = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Table]";
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                sda.Fill(t);
        }
    }

    return t;
}
```

In this example, `r` has the compiler warning.

> Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.

I am aware of the need to check for nulls and such. My question is has anyone figured out how with this new feature to get the compiler to realize that neither `profiles` nor `profiles.Rows` will ever be null? The `t` variable in `ListProfiles` could absolutely return no results, but that wouldn't make `Rows` null, would it?

If I use the null-coalescing operator `??` like this: `profiles.Rows ?? ...` and the warning would go away but I haven't been able to figure out what can go after it to actually work.

I have also tried using the ! operator from [How to suppress Possible Null Reference warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61384377/how-to-suppress-possible-null-reference-warnings/61388468#61388468) but that has no effect. The warning remains. While this works for other types, it doesn't seem to work for `DataRowCollection`.

I have tried various placements of `null` checks but only an explicit in-code suppression seems to have any effect.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61388468/34092

Comment: @mjwills that doesn't work. Adding the ! operator to `profiles!.Rows` still gives the warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nullable value is `r`, not `profiles` or `profiles.Rows`, as correctly identified by the compiler. Just declare it as nullable, then handle the null check in the loop:

```
foreach (DataRow? r in profiles.Rows)
{
    if(r == null) 
        continue;
    // ...
}
```

The reason is that `DataRowCollection` (which is the type of the `Rows` property on the data table) is a non generic enumerable. That's what you get for using .NET 1.0 APIs.

The compiler considers the items of non generic enumerables to be of type `object?`, not `object` (or more accurately, `IEnumerator.Current` is an `object?`), because any such item in the collection could be null, and there are no generics to restrict the items to non nullable values.

Since specifying the type of a `foreach` variable simply inserts a cast for you, the end result is you need to declare the variable itself as nullable, since you can't safely cast a nullable value to a non nullable one.

Comment: Thank you. That makes a lot of sense. If this were more than just a super simple console app I would look at using something other than `DataTable` but it's just not a big enough project.