# What is the correct way to check for "possibly null" references?

Tags: c#, null-check

I have this bit of relevant code:

```
if (boardMap[i,j] != null) {
    Console.Write(boardMap[i,j].color.ToString() + " " + boardMap[i,j].type.ToString());    
}
else {
    Console.Write("X");
}
```

`boardMap` contains potentially null values, which is why I implemented the `if` statement checking if the `boardMap[i,j]` item is null. However, I get a warning in line 2 telling me that `boardMap[i,j]` is possibly null.
How do I fix this -> What is the correct way to do null checks like this?

(Please note, I am very much a beginner with dotnet and C#)

Comment: What VS versoin? While I would move the value out into a variable first (avoid multiple boardMap[i,j] accesses - this smells like a warning error. Given that you DO test for null, unless color can be null (which you do not test) this seriously looks like a parsing error. Which may be fixed with a newer version of Roslyn.

Comment: Keep in mind that `boardMap[i,j].color` and `boardMap[i,j].type` can be null as well.

Comment: Support for arrays is not that impressive to begin with. `A[] a = new A[5]; Console.WriteLine(a[3].ToString());` crashes at runtime but doesn't warn, even though the array is initialized to all `null` values. Obviously verifying initialization of the whole array is a little beyond the reach of static analysis, but still.

Comment: @TomTom It [reproduces](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5EGdiI) for me (i use the release version of .NET 6 and latest VS).

Comment: @TomTom newest VS Code with an up-to-date C# extension, .net framework 6

Comment: @Progman In my case, the `.color` and `.type` fields can't be null, should've included that in the question

Comment: This would warrant a bug report. Unless color or type are nullable, this is a false error imho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a multithreaded app `boardMap[i,j]` could potentially be set to null 10 nanoseconds after you've checked it not to be null. That's (probably) why the compiler now complains.
Of course it depends on your code.
If you're sure that array is only handled by one thread, your null check is safe as is and you can just ignore the warning here.

An easy way to protect you code in a multithreaded scenario (without locking) is to assign the array value to a local variable. And do the null check and the `Console.Write` on that variable. Then the null check is safe. See post by @GuruStron

Answer (score 1):

Currently compiler does not handle this case very well (and arrays [in general](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#arrays)). To help compiler determine the null-state of the item you can use pattern matching with [empty property pattern](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/do-more-with-patterns-in-c-8-0/#property-patterns):

```cs
if (boardMap[i,j] is {} map) 
{
    Console.Write(map.color.ToString() + " " + map.type.ToString());    
}
else
{
    Console.Write("X");
}
```

or introduce a variable:

```cs
var map = boardMap[i,j];
if (map != null) 
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: If the value is null on first call then it's also null on any other call (unless changed). Packing it in a variable will not change that. The empty property pattern would be enough.

Comment: @DanielD It does not change the "truth" but it changes the output of compiler cause currently nullability static flow analysis does not handle the OP case well, while it can handle separate variable. So I agree that  empty property pattern **should** be enough, but it is not for the compiler ATM.

Comment: Well, point for you as OP didn't specify whether he just doesn't want the warning for a possible null value to be displayed anymore, or whether he actually wants to handle a possible null value. Still your first option handles the null value, the latter just removes the warning.

Comment: @DanielD _", the latter just removes the warning."_ no, it handles it as good as the first one. Inside the `if` block `map` will be considered as not null by compiler and outside - compiler will give nullability warnings.

Comment: again you're right, it's late :) ofc both solutions check against null values, just ment it doesn't change anything compared to OP's direct access, except better variable usage (no need to get value from array each time).

Answer (score 1):

As of C# 8.0 and later, you can use the [null-forgiving operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving). Just append ! after whatever might be null. It basically tells the compiler that it should turn off possibly null warnings for this occurrence.

```
if (boardMap[i,j] != null) {
    Console.Write(boardMap[i,j]!.color.ToString() + " " + boardMap[i,j]!.type.ToString());    
}
else {
    Console.Write("X");
}
```

Comment: Not a solution, imho, but a workaround. Because this basically eliminates the nul as possible value - TOTALLY.

Comment: keep in mind that this doesn't solve your null value exceptions at runtime, but simply removes the null warning of the compiler.

Comment: @DanielD JFYI the nullable reference types feature does not guarantee that you will not have the null reference exceptions at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Despite your `if`, the compiler is not able to infer that `boardMap[i,j]` won't be null, so it issues this warning.

**EDIT**
@GuruStron points out that this kind of warning is only issued since C#8. I was not able to find the reference for this, but I'm inclined to believe it. Which implies that if one has this problem, he is using at least C#8.

You can deal generally with this kind of issues in different ways, depending on your needs.

- Use attributes to signal the compiler that the variable won't be null. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis
  and also this question: [How to suppress Possible Null Reference warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61384377/how-to-suppress-possible-null-reference-warnings)
- Use nullable reference types. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references
- Change the code so the compiler will not issue a warning, using `!`, or `?` and `??` operators or the other answers suggestions.
- Ignore the compiler warning, because you know better.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll give the docs you linked a read. I ended up solving the problem by the forgiveness operator `!` for now

Comment: "Use C#8 (if you can)" - OP should already be using it otherwise the  should not be the warning.

Comment: Actually at this point "Use C# 10.0" would possibly be better. I think if you use 10.0 there are different roslyn analyzers and I think I read somewhere that null check was an area they improved.

Comment: Thanks @GuruStron, I'll correct.