# Is there a better way to deal with nullable return that depends on another value?

Tags: c#

I have a method that returns a tuple `(MyEnum, MyObject?)`. There is one and only one enum value that means `MyObject` is not null - all the others mean `MyObject` will be null (and the `string` will have a message).

Something along the lines of

```
(MyEnum response, Package? package) MyMethod()
{
    if (Today == NiceDay)
    {
        return (MyEnum.Happy, new Package("I'm happy!"));
    }
    if (Today == RainyDay)
    {
        return (MyEnum.Pensive, null);
    }
    if (Today == SnowyDay)
    {
        return (MyEnum.Cold, null);
    }
}
```

Obviously, if I try and use `MyMethod().package.message`, the compiler will warn me about the possibility of a null reference. I'm aware of the null-forgiving operator, but that kind of feels like a quick-fix.

Is there a way to "tell" the compiler to expect a value when `MyMethod().response` is `MyEnum.Happy`, and `null` when it is any other value, or is the null-forgiving operator the correct and expected way to deal with this situation?

Comment: I'm confused. You talk about a tuple: `(string, MyEnum, MyObject?)`, but none of your code has the `string` part of the tuple (the first member).  In the one case where you have a non-null last member of the tuple, it's a `Package` instance, not a `MyObject` instance

Comment: It's not the compiler warning you, it's the intellisense of whatever IDE you're using that is telling you that. The intended way to suppress these warnings *is* the null-forgiving operator. However, there are other ways. [Here's an answer going over one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61425855/10601203).

Comment: @Jesse _"It's not the compiler warning you"_ - it actually is compiler, `dotnet build` will result in the same warnings though no IDE is involved.

Comment: Depending on context, one option might be to replace the tuple or enum and package with a polymorphic record type: https://spencerfarley.com/2021/03/26/unions-in-csharp/, and then use pattern matching.

Comment: The "string" member of the tuple was just a remainder of the actual code, and had no effect on the understanding of the questions root issue. As for @Jesse's solution, it works, but Guru's answer below fits better the situation. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently [attributes for null-state static analysis interpreted by the C# compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis) do not support neither specifying nullability of selected properties of returned value nor scenario when specific constant/enum value can be tied to nullability of parameters (except `bool` constants). The closest thing which can be done - return boolean value and tie `out` parameter to the return:

```cs
bool MyMethod(out MyEnum response, [NotNullWhen(true)] out Package? package)
{
    string Today = "";
    response = MyEnum.Happy;
    package = new Package("");
    return true;
}
```

Usage:

```cs
if(MyMethod(out _, out var packageValue))
{
    Console.WriteLine(packageValue.ToString()); // no warning
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So there are many ways to handle null/null warnings.

**First**
If you are 100% sure that the value cannot be null here you can use **!** operator something like this `package!.Message`

**Second**
If You are not sure and there is only one condition in which the value can not be null its better to use the ternary operator like this `var result = MyMethod().response == MyEnum.Happy ? MyMethod().package.message : string.Empty;`

**Third**
you can use **??** operator like this `var message = MyMethod().package?.message ?? "No message found";` or empty string according to your use case.

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion to resolve the issue, instead of the `null` have a static property in the `Package` class that defines an empty package:

```
class Package {
    public static Package None => new Package { Message = "No package." };
}
```

In your code make the return for Package non-nullable and use

```
   return (MyEnum.Pensive, Package.None);
```